# Power of two-sample test of binomial proportions

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, sample-size, sample

Suppose that I have info about a sample, and

In one University, we have 70% females in the population and 30% males. In another University, the numbers are interchanged and 30% are females and 70% are males. Now assume that a random sample of 100 students are picked from each university (total number of observations: 200).

What is the probability that a sample of this size would be able to reject the null hypothesis that the proportion of females in the first population is greater than the second population at an alpha level of 0.05?

How do you find probability of sample and say that it rejects null hypothesis?

Comment: Are you interested in how to do this calculation or in a tool that would do it for you?

Comment: Hi @DimitriyV.Masterov I am interested in the calculation!

Comment: You need to do a power calculation for a one-sided two sample proportion test given your population rates and sample sizes. Power is 1 - Type 2 error rate, which is the quantity you care about here.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I take Success to mean Female. Then the number of Females
in a random sample from University A is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=100,p=0.7)$
and the number of Females in a random sample from University B is
$Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=100,p=0.3).$

**Try one test.** Let's try using `prop.test` in R to analyze one such experiment with 200 students:

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rbinom(1, 100, .7);  y = rbinom(1, 100, .3)
 x; y
[1] 68
[1] 32
prop.test(c(x,y),c(100,100), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
              without continuity correction

data:  c(x, y) out of c(100, 100)
X-squared = 25.92, df = 1, p-value = 3.559e-07
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2307018 0.4892982
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.68   0.32
```

So in *this particular experiment,* the test finds very strong evidence
to reject $H_0: p_a = p_b$ with P-value very near $0.$ [Use of a continuity
correction is not useful for samples of size 100, so I used parameter
`cor=F` in `prop.test` to disallow continuity correction.]

Then the question is whether I somehow got an outrageously atypical
pair of samples in the example above, or whether `prop.test` really
does have good power to detect the large difference in the proportions
of Female students at the two universities, based on samples of $n_a = n_b = 100$ from each university.

**Simulate 100,000 tests to estimate power.** By doing the experiment 100,000 times, I can closely estimate the
power of this test. [Computations in R.]

```
set.seed(722)
pv = replicate(10^5, prop.test(c(rbinom(1,100,.3),
                                 rbinom(1,100,.7)), c(100,100),cor=F)$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.99996
```

The answer is that the power of the test to detect the difference in
proportions (at the 5% level) is above 99%. So it would be extremely rare
for such an experiment not to show a difference in proportions.
Specifically, the answer is 'a probability of almost 1'.

There are several versions of this test (depending on whether a normal
approximation is involved, whether a continuity correction is used,
and whether the test uses a 'pooled' standard error (under the null
hypothesis that proportions are equal). Not knowing the version of
the test you will use, I can't give an algebraic solution. (Also, this
is a 'self-study' problem and you have not shown what you have tried,
so I have no way to guess what approach you might be planning/expected to use.)

**Lower bound on power.** Here is one possible approach that does not use simulation:
If we have $X=60, Y=40,$ then `prop.test` rejects, so it will
also reject for more extreme differences such as $X=61, Y=39,$
and so on. [You might use your favorite test here instead of R's implementation of `prop.test`.]

```
prop.test(c(40,60), c(100,100), cor=F)$p.val
[1] 0.004677735
```

However the exact binomial probability of $P(X \ge 60, Y \le 40)
= P(X \ge 50)P(Y \le 40) = 0.9875.$ So that gives a pretty good idea
that rejection is nearly certain.

```
pbinom(40, 100, .3)*(1-pbinom(40, 100, .7))
[1] 0.9875016
```

The plot below shows that PDFs of $\mathsf{Binom}(100, 0.3)$ and $\mathsf{Binom}(100, 0.7)$ hardly overlap.

[image]

```
x = 0:100;  pdf.x = dbinom(x, 100, .7)
y = 0:100;  pdf.y = dbinom(y, 100, .3)
hdr="PDFs of BINOM(100,.3) [left] and BINOM(100,.7)"
plot(x-.1, pdf.x, type="h", col="blue", lwd=2, 
     ylab="PDF", xlab="Nr of Females", main=hdr)
  points(y+.1, pdf.y, type="h", col="brown", lwd=2)
```

---

*Addendum, per Comment:* The answer is about 12% power.

```
set.seed(723)
pv = replicate(10^5, prop.test(c(rbinom(1,100,.48),
                                 rbinom(1,100,.53)), c(100,100),cor=F)$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.11845
```

Comment: This was really helpful, but I am not sure how would I approach the problem if numbers changed. This is confusing for a beginner, I could solve this question now, but it got messed up: 

52% of the population are males, and 48% are female. In another University, 47% are male, and 53% are females. Suppose that a random sample of 100 people are picked from each University (total observations: 200). 
What is probability that sample of this size would be able to reject null hypothesis that proportion of males in first population are greater than the second population at an alpha level of 0.05?

Comment: I suppose you can guess that the power will be low distinguishing btw $p=.48$ and $p=.53.$ What is puzzling me is why you have not already modified my simulation to approximate the answer. See addendum. // Once again, without knowing exactly what test you plan to use, it is not possible to give an algebraic formula for power. Even then (depending on the test), a formula may be messy.

Comment: I have no experience of the approach you used above, that is the reason it is complicated for me

Comment: Not sure about your interests. If you've never seen R before, I can understand it all looks strange. But if you're going to have much contact with probability and statistics, R can be a huge help. Free. Easy to download from `www.r-project.org`. Versions for Windows, Mac, Unix. Start out using it in the obvious way instead of cell phone calculator. Learn only the bits of immediate use. Lots of online help. Mostly well written. // Maybe you can look at code for 2 power computations in my Ans. Compare. How did I get from 1st to 2nd? // Waaay too much to try to learn all of R. (Nobody ever has.)

Comment: Do you think you can once again explain the steps with the above question I posted in comments, maybe the more I look at solved problems the more I understand?

Comment: Not sure what further explanation you're looking for. Let's start at the _first specific_ thing you don't understand. Point me to that and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: The way you solved the first problem with programming gives a general sense, I tried solving on paper, was some how able to do it, when I approached second question, I got confused

Comment: Do you mean the simulation in the note? If so, I just substituted `.48` and `.53` for `.3` and `.7`, respectively.

Comment: Do you happen to have a handwritten solution and not a computer program?

Comment: Handwritten solution to the problem with .3 and .7 would be as presented in "lower bound on power." Also the figure at the end shows the almost-complete separation of the two distributions that makes that approach feasible. // Problem with .48 and .53 is fundamentally more difficult because the two distributions are so much the same. You introduced that after your Q and my A. So that's not really what I tried to answer. If you object to or don't understand the simulation for the second problem, then you might try normal approximations to to both distributions to get an approximate solution.

Comment: You might try posing the 2nd problem in a separate new question to see what approaches various people present. Show what you have tried. (Maybe mention and link to this pg stating that 2nd problem is sufficiently different that a different approach is requires, and say you're looking for a non-computer solution.)